# regular expression for double consonants

Tags: regex-lookarounds

I have a problem writing regular expression. I want to write a regular expression that replaces all double consonants with a single consonant. 
Please help me to write such a rule in only one line. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a .NET regex that'll find any group of exactly two non-vowels:

```
[^aeiou]{2}
```

The following will work for groups longer than 2:

```
[^aeiou]{2,}
```

For example, this will match "llst" in "allstar."

Slightly uglier, but will match groups of 2 consonants, case-insensitive:

```
[QqWwRrTtYyPpSsDdFfGgHhJjKkLlZzXxCcVvBbNnMM]{2}
```

The following will match two identical non-vowels:

```
([^aeiou])\1
```

For example, this would match the "ll" in "all."

Once you have your regex, just use your chosen language's Regex.Replace function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify the language, I'm going to go ahead and assume Javascript.

This should get you started:

`console.log('babble bubble http htttp www'.replace(/([^aeiou\.,\/=?:\d&\s!@#$%^*();\\|<>"'_+-])\1{1}/gi, "$1"));`

See more here:

http://regexr.com/3ee47